# Invalid ICS file and adding time to existing timestamp in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, icalendar

It's my first time working with ICS files and I'm having trouble getting it to work:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//test.com//NONSGML v1.0//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT 
UID:test@test.com
ATTENDEE;CN=My Self ;RSVP=FALSE
DTSTAMP:TZID=Australia/Sydney:19700101T100000
DTSTART:19700101T100000 
DTEND:19700101T100000
LOCATION:Online
SUMMARY:Test Title 10.0
DESCRIPTION:-
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Not sure if this matters but this is how I've formatted it in Javascript:

```
var icsFile = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\nVERSION:2.0\nPRODID:-//test.com//NONSGML v1.0//EN\nBEGIN:VEVENT \nUID:test@test.com\nATTENDEE;CN=My Self ;RSVP=FALSE\nDTSTAMP:"+ dtstamp +"\nDTSTART:" + start + " \nDTEND:" + start + "\nLOCATION:" + location + "\nSUMMARY:" + summary + "\nDESCRIPTION:" + description + "\nEND:VEVENT\nEND:VCALENDAR";
```

When I run it in the ics validator: https://icalendar.org/validator.html
I get:

```
Error
Invalid DTSTAMP value, must be a valid date-time value near line # 4
Reference: 3.3.5. Date-Time
```

#### Question 1

When I check DTSTAMP, it's correct based on Form#3 : https://icalendar.org/iCalendar-RFC-5545/3-3-5-date-time.html

#### Question 2

How do I go about adding 3 hours into the `DTEND` timestamp in Javascript?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To fix the validation error, you need a semicolon after DTSTAMP instead of a colon:

```
DTSTAMP;TZID=Australia/Sydney:19700101T100000
```

Comment: Hi @Dan Mullin , that has fixed the DTSTAMP error, thanks. Unfortunately it came up with another error:
```
Errors
Lines not delimited by CRLF sequence near line # 1
Reference: RFC 5545 3.1. Content Lines
```

In addition, whenever I attempt to add it to my calendar (on Mac) it doesn't add it :( why is that?

Comment: I’m going to take another look.

Comment: Thanks @Dan Mullin . I noticed that when I paste the text as is in the validator it doesn't work, but when I have it within a `.ics` file, that's when I get that error.